# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n} x^{n}| < \infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}| (|x|^{n-1}+ |x^{n-2}y|+...+|y^{n-1}|) <\infty $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb C$ so that the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n},$  converges absolutely for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Now, we let, $x, y \in \mathbb R$ with $x\neq y;$ and assume that, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n} x^{n}| < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}y^{n}| < \infty . $

> **My Question**: Is it true that, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (|x|^{n-1}+ |x^{n-2}y|+...+|y^{n-1}|) <\infty  $; If yes, how ?; Or we get  a counter example ?

---

I guess the formula, $x^{n}-y^{n} = (x-y) (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1});$ will be useful; but I don't know how; also, I know, that, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n} (x^{n}-y^{n})| < \infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $\sum a_n x^n$ converges absolutely for all $x$ then $\sum a_n x^{n-1}$ converges absolutely for all $x$. This implies that $\sum a_n (|x|+|y|)^n$ converges absolutely for all $|x|+|y|$.

Now

$$\begin{align}\sum |a_n|(|x|^{n-1}+|x|^{n-1}|y|+...+|y|^{n-1})&\leq \sum |a_n|\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}|x|^{n-1-k}|y|^k\right)\\&\leq \sum |a_n|(|x|+|y|)^{n-1}\end{align}$$

where we used that $(|x|+|y|)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}|x|^{n-1-k}|y|^k$.

Comment: why, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|(|x|+|y|)^{n} <\infty ?$

Comment: @DivyangBhimani You said that $\sum a_n x^{n}$ is absolutely convergent for all $x$. So we can replace $x$ by any number we want, in this case by the number $|x|+|y|$.